# Recursive function that generates the permutations of a string

Tags: javascript, strings, recursion, combinatorics

I am looking for a review of my recursive function that generates the permutations of a string. Are there better ways to do this?

```
var permutations = [];

function doPerm(str, arr) {
    if (typeof (str) == 'string') str = str.split('');
    if (str.length == 0) permutations.push(arr.join(''));
    for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
        var x = str.splice(i, 1);
        arr.push(x);
        doPerm(str, arr);
        arr.pop();
        str.splice(i, 0, x);
    }
}
doPerm('', []);
console.log(permutations);
```

Comment: good code , no improvement needed as per this context

Comment: An implementation of Heap's algorithm in JavaScript (mentioned in @amon's answer) can be found [here](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/57893/44723).

Comment: FYI, `typeof` is an operator, not a function. The parentheses around `str` are unnecessary and misleading.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code seems to be correct, and is written in a good style. However, both the interface of your code as well as the algorithm used can be improved.

You currently have a global variable `permutations` which also contains the output. This variable will have to be cleared every time before `doPerm` is invoked. Instead, wrap `doPerm` in another function that provides initialization and input validation:

```
function perms(data) {
    if (!(data instanceof Array)) {
        throw new TypeError("input data must be an Array");
    }

    data = data.slice();  // make a copy
    var permutations = [],
        stack = [];

    function doPerm() {
        if (data.length == 0) {
            permutations.push(stack.slice());
        }
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            var x = data.splice(i, 1);
            stack.push(x);
            doPerm();
            stack.pop();
            data.splice(i, 0, x);
        }
    }

    doPerm();
    return permutations;
}

var input = "abcd".split('');
var result = perms(input);
for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
    result[i] = result[i].join('');
}
console.log(result);
```

Note that this function will operate on arrays of any type and does not special-case strings.

Your algorithm currently relies on splicing elements into and out of the input array. This is somewhat expensive on larger data sets, and it would be better to generate the permutations by swapping. [Heap's Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap%27s_algorithm) does just this.

Comment: Nice, although I'd recommend throwing a `TypeError` instead

Comment: I think `perms` and `doPerm` are horrible names. Why not choose something meaningful?

Comment: @IngoBürk quite right, `doPerm` could be improved – I'd probably use `_perms` or `recurse` in my own code. However, I do not see anything wrong with the name `perms` for a function that calculates permutations. There's a balance to be found between explicitness and terseness, and I think `perms` is a name that strikes a good balance when used for a local variable or method name.

Comment: @amon Personally, I tend to be descriptive, so I'd probably write something like `calculatePermutations`. But even if one doesn't want to do that, I think abbreviating is unnecessary here. `permutations` would be simple and short, but expressive. I like `recurse` for the inner function's name.

Comment: great review, but why not replacing `if (!(data instanceof Array)) {` with `if (!Array.isArray(data)) {`?

Comment: @renatoargh because I didn't know about `Array.isArray()`, and because that method isn't universally available. Could you explain how `Array.isArray()` is better than using `instanceof`?

Comment: @amon, I tend to use `Array.isArray` for redability, but in fact it may not be suitable for cross-browser requirements. Also I don't know any performance differences between both approaches.

Comment: `instanceof Array` would evaluate to true if some madman were to create a constructor, and set the prototype to `[]` (ie: a child of `Array`). `Array.isArray` wouldn't be fooled by that, but perhaps `data.prototype === Array.prototype` or `Object.getPrototypeOp(data) === Object.getPrototypeof([])` is your best bet

Answer (score 5):

I modified your code after getting the error message: "too much recursion" for string of about 6 characters or so."

```
//====================================================
function getPermutations(str){
    //Enclosed data to be used by the internal recursive function permutate():
    var permutations = [],  //generated permutations stored here
        nextWord = [],      //next word builds up in here     
        chars = []          //collection for each recursion level
    ;
    //---------------------
    //split words or numbers into an array of characters
    if (typeof str === 'string') chars = str.split(''); 
    else if (typeof str === 'number') {
      str = str + ""; //convert number to string
      chars = str.split('');//convert string into char array
    }
    //============TWO Declaratives========
    permutate(chars);
    return permutations;
    //===========UNDER THE HOOD===========
    function permutate(chars){ //recursive: generates the permutations
        if(chars.length === 0)permutations.push(nextWord.join(''));            
        for (var i=0; i < chars.length; i++){
            chars.push(chars.shift());  //rotate the characters
            nextWord.push(chars[0]);    //use the first char in the array            
            permutate(chars.slice(1));  //Recurse: array-less-one-char
            nextWord.pop();             //clear for nextWord (multiple pops)
        }
    }
    //--------------------------------
}//==============END of getPermutations(str)=============
```

Some of the names are long, but descriptive.

Features:

1. No longer get the "too much recursion" message.
2. Only one argument is passed to the function.
3. Takes a string or a number argument.
4. Variables are not global but enclosed in the outer function.
5. The inner function does the recursion using closure variables
6. Doesn't use splice, but uses slice only once.

Anything else you can add of value or take away would be appreciated.

Comment: Created an account just to upvote this. By far my favorite expression / explanation of the algorithm. Thank you!

Comment: A beautiful code.

Comment: Wow. Beautiful remake of my post, thanks for sharing this!